# lucene object mapping query

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, lucene.net

I'm querying for `NOT_ANALYZED` Fields in Lucene Object Mapping Version=1.0.3.0

Here's my code to create a document and query, but I'm not getting any result back, does anyone know why?

```
public Document SetDefault() {
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.Add(new Field("Id", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    doc.Add(new Field("Name", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
    doc.Add(new Field("DOJ", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
    doc.Add(new Field("DOR", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
    doc.Add(new Field("Description", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
    doc.Add(new Field("ClearId", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));    
    return doc;
}

public void main()
{
    BooleanQuery bq1 = new BooleanQuery();
    TermQuery SI = new TermQuery(new Term("ClearId", "SS1-14081404142227--kaa-));    
    bq1.Add(SI, Occur.MUST);    
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You are building a query, but are not running any code to execute the query in your example. If you don't provide real code that people can run (or at least pseudo-code of what you would like to do), it is unlikely anyone will be able to answer.

Comment: SetDefault() method  is how i am creating fields in lucene object maping and then i am quring on it to get required result but i don't know how to query on data of fields with special charachters like "SS1-14081404142227--ka" as string